# Dynamic shader in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

CUDA 5 and OpenCL 2 introduce dynamic Parallelism (kernels launched by another kernel via a device API, not by the host API).

Is there an equivalent to this in OpenGL? Is it possible to simulate them with feedback loops? (I think not) They don't miss in OpenGL (maybe in GL 4.3 compute shader) (shadow, texture, etc).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_Shader), it seems that compute shaders in OpenGL don't support dynamic parallelism. You can only launch them with `glDispatchCompute​()` or `glDispatchComputeIndirect​()`.

It is less possible for other shaders to have such support, because they are within the OpenGL processing stages.